# Resource creation stuck as READY: False. How to inspect resource creation and trace errors in Crossplane?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cicd, infrastructure-as-code, crossplane

We have a [Crossplane](https://www.crossplane.io/) setup to create a [ResourceGroup](https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/upbound/provider-azure/azure.upbound.io/ResourceGroup/v1beta1@v0.38.2) and [StorageAccount](https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/upbound/provider-azure/storage.azure.upbound.io/Account/v1beta1@v0.38.2) in Azure (see fullblown [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/jonashackt/crossplane-aws-azure)).

We use the official Azure Provider (meaning: the new Upbound split up provider families) [`provider-azure-storage`](https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/upbound/provider-azure-storage/v0.39.0) and create the following crossplane manifests:

The `Provider` defintion:

```
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-azure-storage
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-azure-storage:v0.39.0
  packagePullPolicy: Always
  revisionActivationPolicy: Automatic
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
```

The `ProviderConfig`:

```
apiVersion: azure.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: ProviderConfig
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  credentials:
    source: Secret
    secretRef:
      namespace: crossplane-system
      name: azure-account-creds
      key: creds
```

The `azure-account-creds` are generated [as described in the getting started guide](https://docs.crossplane.io/latest/getting-started/provider-azure/#create-a-kubernetes-secret-for-azure).

Our `CompositeResourceDefinition`:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: CompositeResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: xstoragesazure.crossplane.jonashackt.io
spec:
  group: crossplane.jonashackt.io
  names:
    kind: XStorageAzure
    plural: xstoragesazure
  claimNames:
    kind: StorageAzure
    plural: storagesazure
  
  defaultCompositionRef:
    name: storageazure-composition

  versions:
  - name: v1alpha1
    served: true
    referenceable: true
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          spec:
            type: object
            properties:
              parameters:
                type: object
                properties:
                  location:
                    type: string
                  resourceGroupName:
                    type: string
                  storageAccountName:
                    type: string
                required:
                  - location
                  - resourceGroupName
                  - storageAccountName
```

Our `Composition`:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Composition
metadata:
  name: storageazure-composition
  labels:
    crossplane.io/xrd: xstoragesazure.crossplane.jonashackt.io
    provider: azure
spec:
  compositeTypeRef:
    apiVersion: crossplane.jonashackt.io/v1alpha1
    kind: XStorageAzure
  
  writeConnectionSecretsToNamespace: crossplane-system
  
  resources:
    - name: storageaccount
      base:
        apiVersion: storage.azure.upbound.io/v1beta1
        kind: Account
        metadata: {}
        spec:
          forProvider:
            accountKind: StorageV2
            accountTier: Standard
            accountReplicationType: LRS
      patches:
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.storageAccountName
          toFieldPath: metadata.name
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.resourceGroupName
          toFieldPath: spec.forProvider.resourceGroupName
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.location
          toFieldPath: spec.forProvider.location
          
    - name: resourcegroup
      base:
        apiVersion: azure.upbound.io/v1beta1
        kind: ResourceGroup
        metadata: {}
      patches:
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.resourceGroupName
          toFieldPath: metadata.name
        - fromFieldPath: spec.parameters.location
          toFieldPath: spec.forProvider.location
```

And finally our `Claim`:

```
apiVersion: crossplane.jonashackt.io/v1alpha1
kind: StorageAzure
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: managed-storage-account
spec:
  compositionRef:
    name: storageazure-composition
  parameters:
    location: West Europe
    resourceGroupName: rg-crossplane
    storageAccountName: account4c8672f
```

Everything is applied via `kubectl apply` and doesn't throw any errors.

Although the StorageAccount has a `READY: False` when looking at `kubectl get crossplane` output.

How can we inspect the crossplane resources, so that we're able to trace down the error. The StorageAccount doesn't appear to be created in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Why is this closed, along many other crossplane questions? There is exaclty 0 question about crossplane on ServerFault or other Stackexchange communities - nor is there a CI/CD tag (where there is a Community for it here along other Cloud Communities)? Also this question seems to help many people - I don't get it. In this reasoning there should be closed any Docker, Kubernetes, CI/CD (GitHub, GitLab - also a Community), Ansible, etc. etc. questions. Really annoying. Sorry to rant here, but don't really know where to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [a great documentation about how to troubleshoot your crossplane resources in the docs](https://docs.crossplane.io/knowledge-base/guides/troubleshoot/), which mainly focusses on running `kubectl describe` and `kubectl get event` on your crossplane resources.

But from crossplane 1.14 on [there are new features included into the crossplane CLI](https://blog.crossplane.io/crossplane-v1-14/). One of these features is the `crossplane beta trace` command, which allows to inspect any crossplane resources & see their respective status and **aims to streamline the troubleshooting process**:

> `trace` to examine live resources and find the root cause of issues
> quickly

Now using the command in our example requires installation of the crossplane CLI first. [According to the docs](https://docs.crossplane.io/latest/cli/) this could be achieved like this:

```
curl -sL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crossplane/crossplane/master/install.sh" | sh
sudo mv crossplane /usr/local/bin
```

Now having crossplane CLI in place we could use it to inspect our `Claim`'s status via the following command:

```
crossplane beta trace StorageAzure managed-storage-account -o wide
```

After the `trace` you need to provide the name of your `Claim` (which is `StorageAzure` in our case) followed by the `metadata.name` (`managed-storage-account` here). The appended `-o wide` helps to see the full error messages if any.

Now this should provide you with valuable insights. We had this case where our Azure credentials were broken and now got a hint finally:

```
$ crossplane beta trace StorageAzure managed-storage-account -o wide
NAME                                             SYNCED   READY   STATUS                                                                                
StorageAzure/managed-storage-account (default)   True     False   Waiting: ...resource claim is waiting for composite resource to become Ready          
└─ XStorageAzure/managed-storage-account-6g2xn   True     False   Creating: Unready resources: resourcegroup, storageaccount                            
   ├─ Account/account4c8672d                     False    -       ReconcileError: ...r_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}:    
   └─ ResourceGroup/rg-crossplane                False    -       ReconcileError: ...r_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}:
```